# Pull Numbers That Have Not Been Drawn

Tags: r, random, generator

Here is the code that I am working with. I want to randomly draw numbers and I want to keep doing this until all the numbers 1:18 have been drawn. I do not want to draw the same number twice.

```
RandomArray <- sample(1:18, 6, replace=F)

RandomArray2 <- sample(1:18,6, replace = F)
RandomArray3 <- sample(1:18,6, replace = F)
RandomArray2 <- ifelse(RandomArray==RandomArray2,
  sample(1:18,6,replace=F),RandomArray2)

RandomArray3 <- ifelse(RandomArray2==RandomArray3,
            sample(1:18,6,replace=F),RandomArray3)
```

The ideal output would be

```
RandomArray [1 2 3 4 5 6] RandomArray2 [7 8 9 10 11 12] RandomArray3 [13 14 15 16 17 18]
```

I have also tried doing

```
x <- 1:18 
test2 <- sapply(x, function(x) 
  if (x == RandomArray) x-RandomArray else x)
```

But that is not right either because I just want to rid of the numbers I have already drawn.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what if I wanted to do names?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "do names"..?

Comment: Sorry not names but characters

Comment: If you start with a vector of characters, like `v = LETTERS` (a built-in equal to A..Z), you can `sample(v)`, which also gives a random permutation. Not sure if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
r_vecs = split(sample(18), 1:3)
```

*How it works.* `sample(18)` is a permutation of 1:18; and 1:3 is "recycled" out to the same length. @akrun pointed out that using `rep(1:3, 6)` in place of the recycled 1:3 can be faster.

---

*Comment.* Best to keep them in a list rather than to mess around with a ton of objects named like `RandomArray*`. A matrix would be another good option:

```
r_vecs = matrix(sample(18), ncol=3)
```

Comment: In some cases, I find the recyling to be slow when compared to `rep`.  +1

Comment: @akrun Thanks; I've added a note.